# Cannot GET / with manually typed URLs - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have installed React Router and am using browserHistory, but when I manually type the URL, I get `Cannot GET /:path`.

Any ideas why this might be?

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from './config/routes';

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

import App from '../components/app';
import Dashboard from '../components/dashboard';
import Expenditure from '../components/expenditure';
import Income from '../components/income';
import Transactions from '../components/transactions';

export default(
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path='expenditure' component={Expenditure} />
        <Route path='income' component={Income} />
        <Route path='transactions' component={Transactions} />
    </Route>
);
```

Clicking on the nav displays the content perfectly with the correct route.

Am using webpack to compile with webpack-dev-server.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect all non-file requests to index.html, which is required for browserHistory to work.

In webpack-dev-server there is an option `historyApiFallback`, which you have to set to `true` to make it happen.

See [webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option) for more information

```
new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    historyApiFallback: true

    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question today and cann't find answer in stackoverflow.
let path in `webpack.config.js`: `output.publicPath` be equal to `devServer.historyApiFallback.index` and **point out html file route**。my `webpack-dev-server` version is 1.10.1 and work well. http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option doesn't work, you must point out html file route.

for example:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: 'build',
        filename: 'bundle-main.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback:{
            index:'build/index.html'
        },
    },
    //其他的配置省略
};
```

`historyApiFallback.index` indicate that when url path not match a true file,`webpack-dev-server` use the file config in `historyApiFallback.index` to show in browser rather than 404 page. then all things about your route change let your js using `react-router` do it.